# External database with redis-connect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis, connect-redis

I'm trying to connect to a 3rd party Redis database with [connect-redis](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis). Any idea what's wrong?

```
app.use(express.session({ store: new RedisStore({host: keys.redis.url, port: keys.redis.port, db: keys.redis.db, pass: keys.redis.pass}), secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
```

> Error: Redis connection to redis://the.db.com:9313 failed -
>   getaddrinfo ENOENT
>       at RedisClient.on_error (/node_modules/connect-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:136:24)
>       at Socket. (/node_modules/connect-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:70:14)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
>       at Array.0 (net.js:562:16)
>       at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)

Comment: Are you sure the redis-server is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The host field of the object passed into the RedisStore constructor function should specify a hostname or IP address and not a url.  This field is passed directly into a redis.createClient call as the host parameter:
http://visionmedia.github.com/connect-redis/